# Request is resent when content type is image on firefox

Tags: java, firefox, servlets

When displaying image in new tab, the same request is being sent again
How to avoid it from happening?

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"image.png\"");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(imageByte);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ohhhh... How do I avoid it?